# Как вывести данные одним списком?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```py
if mys6:
    for row in mys6:
        vkk = row['vk']
        fracc = row['ID']
        if fracc == 'test':
            PEER_ID: int = 2000000013
            vk.messages.send(
                random_id=get_random_id(),
                peer_id=PEER_ID,
                message='\n'.join([f"Уважаемые! {vkk}, {qqwe}."])
            )
        else:
            pass            
    else:
```

Мне нужно вывести в одно сообщение:

```
Уважаемые! @idvk, @idvk2, idvk3 и т.д.
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Сейчас это походит на вырваный кусок кода. Сделайте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve), что бы можно было лучше разобраться в вашем вопросе

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать следующий код:

```
vk_ids = [row['vk'] for row in mys6]
message = f"Уважаемые! {', '.join(vk_ids)}."
vk.messages.send(random_id=get_random_id(), peer_id=PEER_ID, message=message)
```